# JSON API to HTML Koinex API

Tags: php, json, api

This is the link of API https://koinex.in/api/ticker

I need the out put as below

```
ETH:40000
BTC:5290000
LTC:8500
```

I have tried this

```
  $json_string = file_get_contents("https://koinex.in/api/ticker");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

  foreach ($parsed_json->{'price'}->{'inr'} as $item) {
      $title = $item[0];
      $Price = $item[1];
      echo "$title \n $Price\n\n";
  }
```

Please help me in this. This is not working.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Access to koinex? Deserialization from JSON? Output into HTML? Formatting of HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code:-

```
<?php
$json_string = file_get_contents("https://koinex.in/api/ticker");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);

foreach ($parsed_json->prices->inr as $key => $val ){
    echo $key.":".$val."\n";
}

?>
```

Sample OUTPUT:-

```
ETH:40611
BTC:529000
LTC:8500
XRP:44.19
BCH:71490
OMG:800
REQ:10.24
ZRX:88.01
GNT:42.1
BAT:20.48
AE:241.99
TRX:4.23
XLM:20.7
NEO:3825
GAS:1450
XRB:287
NCASH:1.72
AION:150
EOS:940
CMT:23.47
ONT:499
ZIL:7.97
IOST:3.17
ACT:16.15
ZCO:7.78
POLY:50
ELF:76.13
```